# Пишет: ''Ошибка времени выполнения: Путь имеет недопустимую форму.''

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Не могу понять в чём ошибка(Строка указана)

```
const
  key = 2;

function shifrch(arg: char): char;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  result := arg;
  if ord(arg) > 32 then
  begin
    x := ord(arg) + key;
    if x > 255
      then x := x - 255 + 32;
    result := char(x);
  end;
end;

function deshifrch(arg: char): char;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  result := arg;
  if ord(arg) > 32 then
  begin
    x := ord(arg) - key;
    if x < 255
      then x := x + 255 - 32;
    result := char(x);
  end;
end;

procedure shifrs(arg: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(arg) do
  begin
    arg[i] := shifrch(arg[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure deshifrs(arg: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(arg) do
  begin
    arg[i] := deshifrch(arg[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure shifrf(const kfile: string; tr: boolean);
const
  shfile = 'ZasifrF';
var
  infile, outfile: text;
  s: string;
begin
  if tr then
  begin
    assign(infile, kfile);{Тут пишет: Ошибка времени выполнения: Путь имеет недопустимую форму}
    assign(outfile, shfile);
  end
  else
    begin
    assign(infile,shfile );
    assign(outfile, kfile);
    end;
  reset(infile);
  rewrite(outfile);
  while not eof(infile) do
  begin
    if tr then
      begin
      readln(infile,s);
      shifrs(s);
      writeln(outfile,s)
      end
      else 
        begin
        readln(infile,s);
        deshifrs(s);
        writeln(outfile,s)
        end;
  end;
end;

var
  tf: boolean;
  s: string;

begin
  writeln('Введите 1, чтобы шифровать, введите иное, чтобы расшифровать');
  readln(s);
  tf := s = '1';
  if tf then
  begin
    writeln('Введите шифруемый файл');
    readln(s);
  end
  else
      writeln('Введите расшифруемый файл');
  readln(s);
  if tf then
    shifrf(s, tf)
  else
      shifrf(s, tf);
end.
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде как минимум одна ошибка:

```pascal
  if tf then
  begin
    writeln('Введите шифруемый файл');
    readln(s);
  end
  else
      writeln('Введите расшифруемый файл');
  readln(s);
```

Здесь второй вызов `ReadLn` выполняется в любом случае. И если вы там просто вводите пустую строку, то в дальнейшем она передаётся в `Assign`. Исправьте на:

```pascal
IF tf THEN
    WriteLn('Введите шифруемый файл:')
ELSE
    WriteLn('Введите расшифруемый файл:');
ReadLn(s)
```